# Jmeter Running two types of requests concurrently

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I have a specific use case for my web app where I want to demonstrate the following flow:

1. Send Type-1 http requests for the first 15 minutes
2. Start sending Type-2 requests at the 10 minute mark, so they run concurrently with Type-1 requests for 5 minutes. Send Type-2 requests for a total duration of 15 minutes.

I'm having issues formulating my test plan to create this test. Currently I have one thread group with two HTTP requests samplers under it (one for type 1 and one for type 2). I've set the scheduled duration for this thread group to 25 minutes. Under each of the Http Request samplers, I have a throughput shaping timer. The first one is simply set to run for 15 minutes, the second is set to "wait" (rps is .000001 for the first 10 minutes of the test) and then start sending requests at the 10 minute mark for 15 minutes.

I think the second throughput timer is being ignored though. Type-1 and Type-2 requests both start being sent as soon as I start the test, suggesting only the first throughput shaping timer is being used for both samplers. If I remove the first throughput shaping timer, then the second one is used for both http request samplers.

Can you only have one throughput shaping timer per thread group, and if so, how else could I make a test to have the second sampler wait 10 minutes in the same thread group?

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? If ok you should accept it and upvote

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 thread groups, one per request type.

Configure on each the scheduler:

- for type 1, start immediatelyvand last 15 minutes
- for type 2, start after 10 minutes and last for 15 minutes.